# Почему не работает calc css?

Tags: css

Использую `smart-grid`, не работает calc, подскажите почему?

Проблема наблюдается во всех браузерах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для операторов "+" или "-" - необходимо задавать единицу измерения https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/yvnsap95/

Comment: @soledar10 спасибо, помогло. Мне не нужны были отступы, я и поставил 0, а надо было 0px

Comment: если не нужен отступ - зачем использовать calc, если можно явно задать ширину?

Comment: в smart-gride это прописывается, я просто использую

Comment: Оформите полноценный ответ или закрывайте вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло указание величины(px) после нуля, внутри скобок calc